# Apps constantly disconnecting from the internet

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, internet, data-connection

I've got a new phone running Android 4.4.2 and whenever I close an app, it disconnects, i.e whenever I close Messenger, it stops being connected to my WiFi so I get no notifications until I open the app, when it reconnects and everything comes through. All apps are doing this, on WiFi and on data.

I can't find anywhere to manage background internet usage and was just wondering if there's a (probably very simple) way to sort it out?

Comment: There's another possibility: the app got killed by the system just after you close it, preventing push notification to be sent. May I know what's your device model?

Comment: My model is a Lenovo S856. I'm not sure what the cause is, I just noticed that I dont get any whatsapp/messenger/snapchat push notifications, until I reopen the app and let it reconnect to the network

Answer (score 0):

I think your apps are being killed by the System or a  task Killer. I solve the same problem yesterday by Downloading this App: 
[Watchdog Task Manager Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zomut.watchdoglite)
It will prevent the apps you add into its "whitelist" from being killed.